My csv contact list after update to list manager is showing 0 recipient
I am working on EXM, so i have created contact list csv and uploaded it in List manager in my local, but after that it is showing as 0 recipients.

How to fix it??
Note: This issue is only occurring in my local, I can see contacts number in my stage.

You can try rebuilding xdb index from the xConnect Collection Search IndexWorker folder with the below command.
Folder Name: {{XConnectFolder}}/App_Data/jobs/continuous/IndexWorker
Sitecore.XConnectSearchIndexer.exe -rr


Once rebuild is done, you can restart the app pool, thereafter you should be able see to the recipent inside the Contact List.
Hope this helps!!!

You can resolve this by rebuilding xDB Index for xConnect in Sitecore. Please follow the below steps

Go to the IndexWorker Job folder (Ex. C:\inetpub\wwwroot\{xConnect website}\App_Data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker

Open command prompt in Administrator mode.

Run below command as per your Sitecore version:
For Sitecore 9.x – XConnectSearchIndexer -rr
For Sitecore 10.x – Sitecore.XConnectSearchIndexer.exe -rr

Restart App pool


Hope this helps  !!!
